# Postgres Password Authentication Failed

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, postgresql-12

I am running a Postgres 12 database on Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

I can connect to the database with `sudo -u postgres psql` without any issues, and can view and create new databases and users.

I created a new user with `CREATE USER myusername WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword';` and psql returns `CREATE ROLE`.

However, when I try to log in as this user with the password that I set with `psql -h localhost -U myusername`, I get `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myusername"`.

I have tried changing the password on this user multiple times with `ALTER USER myusername WITH PASSWORD 'newpassword';` and psql returns `ALTER ROLE`.

A common solution I have found, such as [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24774/postgresql-changing-password-for-a-user-is-not-working), is to modify the `pg_hba.conf` file.

My `pg_hba.conf` file is:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

I have tried modifying both the first and second lines to `md5` and `ident`, and restarted the postgres server each time, to no avail. I have also tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling Postgres, which does not work either.

Is there anything I am missing? Anything else that I can do to try and fix this? Thanks!

Comment: This should work: are your sure that you have only one PG instance running on Windows ? Could you check that this PG instance port number is 5432  with `show port` ?

Comment: @pifor well this was the issue. I had an instance of Postgres running on Windows which I had to stop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference to those who encounter this problem on Windows Subsystem for Linux, I used the Command Prompt to search the running services and see if a Postgres service was running with `sc queryex type=service state=all | find /i "postgres"`.

This returned:

```
SERVICE_NAME: postgresql-x64-9.5
DISPLAY_NAME: postgresql-x64-9.5 - PostgreSQL Server 9.5
```

I then was able to use `sc stop` with the service name to stop the service:

```
sc stop postgresql-x64-9.5
```

This solved the password authentication issue.

Comment: This was driving me crazy. Thank you.

Comment: @LeviMurray I'm glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Doublecheck if there is another PostgreSQL instance running on the default port number.